# Don't Understand why matplotlib bar width is not constant

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I think there has been a lot of posts about this. But I cant really understand what is going on. Based on the other stack overflow questions, I'm guessing the reason why my barplot widths are not constant is due to a 'non linear axis?'

I don't really understand why that is causing my matplotlib barplot widths to not be the same:

```
# Initialize Data Frame
df = pd.DataFrame({r'$l$': range(1,4)}, index = range(1, 4))

# Add other stuff
df[r'Frequency (emitted photon) / $\frac{k_B \Theta_R}{h}$'] = (df[r'$l$'] * (df[r'$l$'] + 1) - 
                                                                (df[r'$l$'] - 2)*(df[r'$l$'] - 1))

df[r'Probabilities $p(l)$'] = (np.exp((-df[r'$l$']/300) * (df[r'$l$'] + 1)) / 
                              (((2*df[r'$l$'] + 1) * np.exp((-df[r'$l$']/300) * (df[r'$l$'] + 1))) + 
                              ((2 * df[r'$l$'] - 1) * np.exp(-((df[r'$l$'] - 2)/300) * (df[r'$l$'] - 1)))
                              ))

# Graph Settings
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, figsize = (16,8))


axes.bar(df[r'Frequency (emitted photon) / $\frac{k_B \Theta_R}{h}$'],
         df[r'Probabilities $p(l)$'], label = 'Probability vs Frequency', color = 'red', width = 0.1)

# Graph Settings
axes.set_title('Probabilities against frequency(emitted photon)', fontsize = 20)
axes.xaxis.set_ticks(range(0, 13))


# Display Graph
plt.show()
```

Even though i had set the width to be 0.1, the bar chart is incredibly ugly

[image]

Why is the width for the 1st bar okay, but the rest so fat? How do i correct it such that all the widths are the same?

Comment: Instead of `ax.bar(df["col1"], df["col2"])` use `ax.bar(df["col1"].values, df["col2"].values)`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Hi! It works! But can you explain why the .values are needed? I worked with barplots before and never had to use the .values? Thank you!

Comment: It's a bug that happens for a specific combination of pandas and matplotlib versions. `.values` turns the pandas Series into numpy arrays, and plotting numpy arrays has always been frictionless in matplotlib.